DUPLICATES_DETECTED: Get IDs of matching records?
I'm working through a data migration effort that includes upserting many thousands of accounts via Bulk API. There is a substantial overlap between the incoming data and existing Salesforce accounts.
My data migration script does its best to catch potential duplicates, but it doesn't have the full power of fuzzy matching, so some duplicates are first identified when I try to insert an account in Salesforce. This is the error message I get back:

DUPLICATES_DETECTED:This record looks like an existing record. Make sure to check any potential duplicate records before saving.

My duplicate rule is pretty stringent. I tend to trust it when it tells me something is a duplicate.
I'd like to parse this error message and do an update of the existing matching account instead of inserting (assuming there is only one matching account). But the error message doesn't give me the IDs of whatever existing accounts it thinks are a match for my incoming account. So I have to do a lot of manual searching in Salesforce to match things up properly.
I have hundreds of incoming accounts with this error. Is there any way to get at the existing account IDs programmatically?

I strongly recommend using a 3rd party data tool like Apsona that has a CSV file matching feature with fuzzy matching.  That will give you the existing IDs where applicable.   If not, you'll have to use the Apex FindDuplicates class to do that matching as a first pass, and then execute your upsert in a second pass.  That is a significant effort for a one-shot migration.
